# Is SCIP safe to call from multiple threads?

Tags: scip

We need to solve many different instances of a problem, where each problem is completely separate from the others. Is SCIP (SCIPsolve) safe to call from multiple threads this way?

I did find some information on [SCIPsolveParallel](https://www.scipopt.org/doc-5.0.1/html/CONCSCIP.php), but this appears to be about working on the same problem using multiple threads. There is also [SCIPsolveConcurrent](https://www.scipopt.org/doc-5.0.1/html/group__PublicSolveMethods.php#ga5c91076d044744834bc75ad85d13a2f4), but there is little information on what it is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not a problem.
There exists a build flag `THREADSAFE` that you can make sure is enabled (though it is on by default).